# C++ Port Scanner

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to do a port scanner in c++ so I can get IP address from certain devices in my network which had a certain port opened. I implemented a timeout because as I'm testing every single IP address in my network if in a time I didn't get a response it automatically closes the connection.

If I put this timeout about 30 useconds it just detect all devices closed, and if I put a much more bigger value it hangs and never finishes.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;    

static bool port_is_open(string ip, int port){

    struct sockaddr_in address;  /* the libc network address data structure */
    short int sock = -1;         /* file descriptor for the network socket */
    fd_set fdset;
    struct timeval tv;

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str()); /* assign the address */
    address.sin_port = htons(port);

    /* translate int2port num */
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(sock, &fdset);
    tv.tv_sec = 0;             /* timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 50;

    if (select(sock + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv) == 1)
    {
        int so_error;
        socklen_t len = sizeof so_error;

        getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);

        if (so_error == 0){
            close(sock);
            return true;
        }else{
            close(sock);
            return false;
        }
    }        
    return false;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){    

    int i=1;        
    int port = 22;        
    while (i<255) {            
        string ip = "10.0.60.";                        
        std::string host = std::to_string(i);
        ip.append(host);            
        if (port_is_open(ip, port)){                
            printf("%s:%d is open\n", ip.c_str(), port);                
        }            
        i++;
    }           
    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: 30 useconds?  30 microseconds timeout?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `tv.tv_usec = 50` equals 50 usec

Comment: and 30u sec is quite short, on LAN it would be around 24 milliseconds connect time, so I would put 100-200 milliseconds as the timeout if its on LAN, if its WAN, I would use higher values

Comment: Nothing is going to happen in 50us on your network.

Comment: @nrathaus 'quite short'?  It's shorter than an undernourished dwarf after being run over by a road-roller.

Comment: No need to exaggerate @MartinJames :)

Comment: If you want your port scanner to run faster overall, but with with a sane timeout, you could make 256 asynchronous connects or run 256 threads. Connect timeouts are usually measured in seconds, not microseconds.  On a local LAN, to allow for busy boxes and slow routers/hubs, I suggest a second.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your logic into async calls and start in parallel with a reasonable timeout (like 10 seconds since 30us has rather no sense in standard conditions). Threading will speedup your program around 255 times and it will be finished, in worst case, just after this timeout occurs:

```
...
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
...

void task(std::string ip, int port){
    if (port_is_open(ip, port))
        cout << ip << ":" << port << " is open\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){        
    const std::string ip_prefix = "10.0.60.";
    const int port = 22;
    std::vector<std::thread *> tasks;

    for (int i=0; i<255; i++){      
        std::ostringstream ip;
        ip << ip_prefix << i;
        tasks.push_back(new std::thread(task, ip.str(), port));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<255; i++){
        tasks[i]->join();
        delete tasks[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to compile it like this: `g++ -std=c++11` or `g++ -std=c++0x -pthread` (for older GCC).

Comment: +1 but, don't you read all the multithread-tag posts about only creating as many threads as there are cores?  :))

Comment: @Martin James: It's designated for the machines of the future;] But seriously, I didn't see these topics about only creating as many threads as there are cores. Multithreaded programming existed in the past also on single core processors and has not always been about hardware parallelization of heavy computations, which takes most of processor power for each core. It's also about improvement of efficiency, by using time that would otherwise be wasted by the processor, while it has nothing to do but waiting for e.g. memory, disk or network operations to complete.

Comment: @Martin James: (...) Here we are just sending bits over the wire in each thread and we do not want to block each step just because we are waiting for the response. I think such logic fits here clearly (see [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97615/what-can-multiple-threads-do-that-a-single-thread-cannot)), but I may be wrong.

Comment: Heh - I was being sarcastic.  Your solution is fine, which is why I upvoted it:)